# Creating a Download link to a physical file on internal drive, within an MVC 4 Razor Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to do this in an MVC4 application:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td><a href="@item.DownloadUrl">Download Document</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

The view renders fine, but when I click on the link nothing get downloaded.

when I hover over `@item.DownloadUrl` I can see that it has a value of: `C:\Websites\Documents\105.pdf` , which is correct.

When I hover over the link itself I get to see this URL instead of the above: `file:///C:/Websites/Documents/105.pdf`, which shows that 'file:///' has been added to the beginning.

I wonder how can I do this correctly. I know there might be some IIS Configuration before I can let an application link access the local drive files, but this is clearly not relevant so far or is it? I am running this in Visual Studio in debug mode..

NB. the `@item.DownloadUrl` is produced at runtime based on some code such as:

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
    la.DownloadUrl = Path.Combine(DocumentsLocation, Reader["Id"] + ".pdf");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Try to download the file with another extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the issue:

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(DocumentsLocation, name + ".pdf"));
string fileName = name + ".pdf";
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Thanks for all those who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use `Server.MapPath` to link to a remote file on the server. What you are doing right now, is linking to physical file on the client's machine.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(DocumentsLocation, Reader["Id"] + ".pdf"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but Server.MapPath doesn't accept a physical path that's why this didn't work.

Comment: Server.MapPath actually does the opposite of what the question asks and maps a relative URL to a physical location on the server